# Mongojs Can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: mongodb, angular, http-headers, mean, mongojs

This is obviously a known issue, but I have no idea how to fix it on my MEAN project.
it seems that multiple requests are sent. 
I have tried every solution I could find (old or more recent). unsuccessful so far.

res.end()
res.redirect('/')

nothing seems to do the trick.

[image: error in console]

[image: error in the terminal console]

**this is my code where I handle my HTTP Methods**

```
//delete
router.delete('/task/:id', function(req, res, next) {
    let post = mongojs.ObjectId(req.params.id)
    db.tasks.remove({_id: mongojs.ObjectId(req.params.id)}, function(err, task){
        res.status(200).res.json(task)
        return res.end()

        console.log('SERVER - post ' + req.body.title + ' successfully deleted')

        if (err) {
            res.send('error message ' + err)
        }    
    })
})

//update
router.put('/task/:id', function(req, res, next) {
    var task = req.body
    var updateTask = {}

    updateTask.isDone = task.isDone
    updateTask.title = task.title

    if(!updateTask) {
        res.status(404).send({
            "error": "bad request"
        })

    } else {
        db.tasks.update({_id: mongojs.ObjectId(req.params.id)}, updateTask, {}, function(err, task){
            res.status(200).res.json(task)
            return res.end()

            if (err) {
                res.send('error message ' + err)
            }
        })
    }


})
```

this is an angular app, so here is my service file. although, this is no issue related to the client

```
public deletePost(post: Post) {
    console.log('SERVICE - post ' + post._id  + ' successfully deleted')
    return this.http.delete('http://localhost:1234/api/task/' + post._id)
      .map(res => res.json)

  }

  public updatePost(postId : string, newText:string) {

  }

  public addPost(newPost: Post) {
    var headers = new Headers();//??
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    console.log('successfully added (service)' + newPost.title)
    let body = JSON.stringify({title: newPost.title, isDone:false});
    console.log(body)


    return this.http.post('http://localhost:1234/api/task', JSON.parse(body),{headers})
    .map(res => res.json());  
  }
```

Comment: resolved! I was indeed sending the request twice in the client and the in server.

Comment: replaced:  res.status(200).res.json(task)  return res.end()

Answer (score 0):

resolved! 
I was indeed sending the request twice in the client and the in server.

in my post.service.ts (client), I was already sending an answer with:
**res => res.json()**

**replaced :**
res.status(200).res.json(task)
return res.end()

**with only :**
res.status(200)